# C++ Replacing Functions with Macros

Tags: c++, c

We have an existing function implementation in our C++ code:

```
void Function(int param)
{
    printf("In Function\n");
}

int main()
{
    Function(10);
    return 0;
}
```

I wish to change it to call another function (by help of a macro declaration) which would accept additional params like  **FILE** and **LINE** (for debugging purpose) and then call the actual function:

```
#define Function(param) Function_debug(param, __FILE__,  __FUNCTION__,  __LINE__) \
{\
    printf("In Function_debug [%s] [%s] [%d]\n", file, func, line); \
    Function(param);\
}
```

But the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define Function(param) Function_debug(param, __FILE__,  __FUNCTION__,  __LINE__) \
{\
    printf("In Function_debug [%s] [%s] [%d]\n", file, func, line); \
    Function(param);\
}

void Function(int param)
{
    printf("In Function\n");
}

int main()
{
    Function(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Translates TO:

```
void Function_debug(int param, "temp.cpp", __FUNCTION__, 9) { printf("In Function_debug [%s] [%s] [%d]\n", file, func, line); Function(int param);}
{
    printf("In Function\n");
}

int main()
{
    Function_debug(10, "temp.cpp", __FUNCTION__, 16) { printf("In Function_debug [%s] [%s] [%d]\n", file, func, line); Function(10);};
    return 0;
}
```

which gives compilation errors.

Please direct me how to achieve the objective?

Comment: I suggest not to use same identifier for macro and function name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally you'd do something like this:

```
#if DEBUG
#define FUNCTION(param) Function_debug(param, __FILE__,  __FUNCTION__,  __LINE__)
#else
#define FUNCTION(param) Function(param)
#endif

void Function(int param)
{
    printf("In Function\n");
}

void Function_debug(int param, const char * file,  const char * func,  int line)
{
    printf("In Function_debug [%s] [%s] [%d]\n", file, func, line); \
    Function(param);
}

int main()
{
    FUNCTION(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried : g++ -DDEBUG temp.cpp but the code execution does not executes the debugging method

Comment: If would need to be `g++ -DDEBUG=1 ...`, or you could change `#if DEBUG` to `#ifdef DEBUG` if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

1st rule: use different name for your macro and the function that it replaces.
2nd rule: if using gcc, wrap the code block in parenthesis ({ }) to make your functions callable from as if `printf("%f\n",sqrt(2.0));`

`#define Function(a) ({ printf("Debug stuff\n"); orig_function(a);})`

Comment: Better to use the canonical `do { ... } while (0)` if you must use macros as functions.

Comment: @PaulR: That only solves the problems related to extra/missing colons and line breaks.

Comment: The main problem it fixes is the if/else problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should first implement a second function and then in your macro just redirect your code to it, in your version you implement the function everywhere that use macro:

```
void function( int param )
{
    // do something interesting here
}
void function_debug( int param, char const* fileName, unsigned line, char const* fn)
{
    // debug position here
    function( param );
}

#ifndef NDEBUG
#    define Function( param )    function_debug( param, __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCION__ )
#else
#    define Function( param )    function( param )
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you add the debug print into `Function`?

```
void Function(int param)
{
    #ifdef DEBUG
    //debug stuff
    #endif
    printf("In Function\n");
}
```

Comment: No but this would not provide from where the function is getting called