# C Hooking a library function call

Tags: c, hook

I have a C library source code and its configuration file, I can rebuild it at any time. There is a library function foo() which I want to replace due to its misbehaviour. I should not edit the library source, only the configuration file can be modified. Is there a way how to replace all calls from foo() to bar() with this restriction?

I tried to use a macro definition:

```
#define foo    bar
```

That does not help though, as it replaces the function name (declaration and definition) as well.

I found a similar thread: [C++ Replacing Functions with Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250163/c-replacing-functions-with-macros) . The problem is that I cannot modify the source, and there is no conditional code. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: Simple example to clarify the problem. Let's say the library has a utility function `plus()` for summing two integers and a function `minus()` for subtracting two integers, which internally calls `plus(a,-b)`. But since the function `plus()` does not compute the correct result, I wrote a function `myplus()` which works well. Now the issue is *how to force the library to call `myplus()` instead of `plus()`*.

Comment: Consider instead linking with your new implementation.  Or if you must your linker may allow you to link with both but have the new one take precedence.  Linux and other OSs allow `LD_PRELOAD`, for example.

Comment: This is certainly possible with the linker, but the details will be platform-specific. What platform and toolchain are you using?

Comment: I need to link with both implementations, as there is much more code in that library source file. I am looking for a portable solution. My linker is IAR ELF Linker for ARM. So does any clear, portable solution exist?

Answer (score 0):

Add your implementation of `foo` in your source code. In that function, call `bar`. The linker should pick up your version of `foo` ahead of the version in the library.

Comment: I tried that, but my linker (IAR ELF Linker for ARM) complains about duplicate definitions and exits.

Comment: @yman, I don't know about that linker. I am afraid I can't help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "foolib.h"

#define foo bar

void bar()
{
    //foo() replaced with bar()
}
```

So long as your #define statement comes after the #include then it will not rename the function definition inside the library. This technique is used all the time.

Comment: Hi @mark-ch, thank you for your suggestion, but that would not change the internal library calls. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: if you're using eclipse or a derivative of it, then you can set definitions on a per-file basis. Choose the C file from the library containing foo(), right click --> properties --> build --> compiler --> advanced options --> predefined symbols and set a pre-define foo=foonotlinked. if you build then, foo() will be missing and unresolved, so you can create your own. Still, any calls to foo() from within the same file will use the old one :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming foo() resides inside foo.c, you can do the following:

Instead of adding foo.c to your project, add foowrap.c, which would be:

```
#define __FOOWRAP__
#include "foo.c"
```

In the header where you did your original #define, do instead:

```
#ifndef __FOOWRAP__
#define foo bar
#endif
```

This also assumes foo() is not called inside foo.c itself. If it is, I think there's no way to solve the problem without changing that source file.